# Can't connect to node server from android while i can from browser

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

i have created a node server that i wanna connect from different devices.
here is the code for server ...

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
     console.log(socket.id);
     socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
     });
});

http.listen(2000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:2000');
});
```

i can simply connect to the server by browser. but i can't connect using android device. here is my android side code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Socket mSocket;
public Socket getSocket(){
    if(mSocket==null){
        try{
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://localhost:2000");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error connecting" , " to server");
        }
    }
    return mSocket;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Socket socket = getSocket();
      socket.connect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless the node server is running on the Android device your running the app from, localhost is not going to work. On what device are you running the node server?

Comment: sorry i have written the "localhost" by mistake. i place the IP address of my computer. the node server is running on my laptop

Comment: `connect to the server by browser.` ? Browser on your Android device?

Comment: Errors? Exception? Please show the LogCat. `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: yes the browser on my android device can connect to the server, but the only problem is that i can't connect from android application...

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException?`. Answer all questions!

Comment: where can i find NetworkOnMainThreadException?